# Facebook Login auth dialog and permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

I've set required permissions for my app in "Settings/Auth dialog". However they doesn't show up when I add generic login button

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxx',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put a "data-perms" attribute in your fb-login-button class div.  Here's what I mean:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-perms="email,user_checkins">
        Login with Facebook
</div>
```

Here's a link to the facebook doc page that will tell you all about it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

The code I just pasted in there is about halfway down the page.  They show you exactly what you need to do to make the login and permissions work.

Hope that helps!

-Kyle

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Your method indeed works. Meanwhile I've been experimenting with FB.login and have similar issue. Login dialog only asks for permissions that I explicitly include in "perms" or "scope". So I'm not sure what is the point of setting permissions in "Settings/Auth Dialog" (I mean https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ID/auth).